# Clear my doubt regarding this probabililty concept.

Tags: probability

A bag contains 2 red and 3 green balls. 2 balls are draw at random. Find the probability that the ball is red and green.What is the correct solution to the problem.

Solution 1- 2/5 * 3/4 = 3/10 i.e probability of getting red multiplied by probability of getting green from the remaining balls.

Solution 2- 2C1 * 3C1/ 5C2 = 2*3/10=3/5 Using combinations.

I cant understand the difference between the two. In many books answer is given as solution 1, simple way. Whereas is some others for the same kind of questions, they are doing using combinations.
In which type of questions can we use the simple method and when we have to take combinations for finding the probability.

Comment: "Find the probability that the ball is red and green." I think the incorrect English might actually be causing confusion at that critical point in the statement of the problem. If there are multiple balls in question, we shouldn't refer to "the" ball, because the word "the" implies that the thing we're referring to is unique. Better phrasing might be: "Two balls are drawn at random without replacement. Find the probability of selecting both a red ball and a green ball."

Comment: What differene will it make in the answer?

Comment: Is it necessary the term without replacement has to be mentioned. Usually if it is not mentioned anything it is assumed as without replacement. only when it is explicitly said that with replacement we calculate like that

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the question is asking the probability of getting a red ball first and then green ball, while you are calculating the probability that you get a red ball and a green ball, not caring about the order.

Notice that if you divide your answer by 2, you get the textbook solution. This is because you must divide by 2! = 2 to get only the case where you get red ball first and then the green ball.

So basically first solution requires first red ball and second green ball, while the second solution does not require order.

Comment: I think the question is asking probability one gets $1$ red ball and $1$ green ball.

Comment: Derek Luna, isn't the probability of getting red first and then green precisely 2/5 * 3/4 = 3/10, whereas the probability of getting red and green is 3/5

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but the way he wrote it up above makes me question which one he meant.

Comment: Derek Luna, but since the book says the solution is 1, it must be first red ball and next green ball no?

Comment: "In many books answer is given as solution 1, simple way. Whereas is some others for the same kind of questions, they are doing using combinations". It is not obvious exactly which situation or book he is referring to. Perhaps clearly explain to him the differences in your answer since there is no context.

Comment: So in the first solution we consider order and in case of combination order is not considered, is that it?

Comment: @Undertaker yeah exactly

Comment: Actually i didnt meant to say solution 1 was the correct answer to the question. What i meant was  for the same kind of questions i have seen both solution coming up in different sources, giving ifferent answers.

Comment: @Undertaker okay then, but yeah the gist is the first is the solution to question of red first and green later

Comment: If in question it is mentioned as with replacing, can we do that suing combinations?

Comment: @Undertaker replacement means you put the ball back, so that's entirely different question.

Comment: @Undertaker pretty much I think

Comment: 1 more doubt. If I say ist green and then red, then also i get the same probability.. how is that

Comment: If according to what you said in the first solution order matters. But in whichever order we took, the probability will remain same doesnt it as we are simply multiplying only..